# JSPM Map For Dependencies Not Resovling Path Correctly

Tags: systemjs, jspm, angularfire2

I'm having significant frustration with JSPM, this is just the latest problem out of many.

I've installed `angularfire2` via JSPM via - `sudo jspm install npm:angularfire2` (Yes, SUDO. Doesn't work without SUDO!!) which *should* have installed `@angular` dependencies. The generated package json looks like this-

```
"jspm": {
  "dependencies": {
    "angularfire2": "npm:angularfire2@^2.0.0-beta.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "npm:typescript@^1.8.10"
  }
}
```

And the generated config looks like this-

```
System.config({
  baseURL: "/",
  defaultJSExtensions: true,
  transpiler: "typescript",
  typescriptOptions: {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
  paths: {
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*"
  },

  packages: {
    "app": {
      "main": "./app.ts",
      "defaultExtension": "ts"
    }
  },

  map: {
    "angularfire2": "npm:angularfire2@2.0.0-beta.2",
    "typescript": "npm:typescript@1.8.10",

    ...

    "npm:angularfire2@2.0.0-beta.2": {
      "@angular/common": "npm:@angular/common@2.0.0-rc.2",
      "@angular/compiler": "npm:@angular/compiler@2.0.0-rc.2",
      "@angular/core": "npm:@angular/core@2.0.0-rc.2",
      "@angular/platform-browser": "npm:@angular/platform-browser@2.0.0-rc.2",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0-rc.2",
      "firebase": "npm:firebase@3.0.5",
      "rxjs": "npm:rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6"
    }

    ...
  }
});
```

So when I refresh the page of the application I see it imports `angularfire2.js` correctly, then tries to import `@angular/platform-browser-dynamic.js`. But the address it is trying to import at is- `http://localhost:8000/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic.js` which is the wrong path! I imagine it's because the first line of my `app.ts` (and the starting point of the application) has this line- `import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';`. But what WHY doesn't JSPM map this correctly? Do I need to install these packages separately? If so- WHY is there such a thing as package dependencies?

Expected: When resolving this import, the `/jspm_packages/npm/**` address should be resolved.

Got: SystemJS attempts to load package from the web root `/`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually add the following in the map.

```
"@angular/common": "npm:@angular/common@2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/compiler": "npm:@angular/compiler@2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/core": "npm:@angular/core@2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/platform-browser": "npm:@angular/platform-browser@2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0-rc.2",
```

Not sure if that's the real solution but it works. *The future is here.*